# Google Sheets' MONTH function on an empty cell returns 12

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

Is this an expected behaviour that month(ref) returns `12` when the ref is an empty cell?

I would have thought that this is a serious bug.
Am I correct?

No mention of that behaviour in the official docs:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052?hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, yes it is expected behavior. All of the time/date based formulas default to lowest/highest value when there is no real reference.

[image: 0]

To prevent it, you are supposed to perform a simple logic check for real data:

```
=IF(LEN(A1), MONTH(A1), )
```




```
=IF(A1<>"", MONTH(A1), )
```

Also, Google Documentation is way too empty!

Comment: Excellent answer